# Error: Certificate Authority file is too old. ..\modules\civicrm\vendor\totten\ca-config\src\CA\Config/cacert.pem

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Today we wanted to access our civicrm site which is hosted within a bitnami stack but we receive the following error:

Certificate Authority file is too old. Please contact the system administrator. See also: C:\Bitnami\civicrm-5.37.2-0\apps\civicrm\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\totten\ca-config\src\CA\Config/cacert.pem

[image]

We can't open the civicrm site.

I looked up the expiring date from that cacert.pem file / Global Sign Root CA but the date is far in the future (28.01.2028).

Does anyone know what is causing that problem and probably how to fix it?

I tried google but with no success.

We run civicrm version 5.45.1 on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/totten/ca_config/issues/2. Core hasn't been updated yet but you can composer require totten/ca-config:~22.05

Answer (score 0):

So that's something I didn't expect....

After digging a bit within our Root Certificates I found out that the name of the current GlobalSign Root CA is actually "GlobalSign Root CA - R1" (in our certificate vault at least).

Inside the cacert.pem file however the name is listed as "GlobalSign Root CA" followed by the Certificate Hash.

After editing the file cacert.pem and adding the "- R1"-part and refreshing the site it immediately worked.

I really don't know why on earth and especially how this got messed up.

Anyway it's working now.